# JPanel EAST and CENTER panels seem to overlay

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, border-layout

I've looked at multiple similar posts but none seem to have the same problem as mine, which seems relatively simple. I have the following code:

```
public PlayScreen(Player player){
    this.player = player;
    playScreen = new JPanel();
    playScreen.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setTowerButtons();
    playScreen.add(towerButtons, BorderLayout.EAST);     //line 6
    setDetailLabels();
    playScreen.add(detailPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
    setMap("map.png");
    playScreen.add(new JButton("hello"), BorderLayout.CENTER);     //line 10
    playScreen.setVisible(true);
}

public class View {
private JFrame frame;
private Container contentPane;
private Player player;
private LoadScreen loadScreen;
private PlayScreen playScreen;
public View(Player player){
    frame = new JFrame("Display");
    contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.player = player;
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.pack();
}

public void makeLoadScreen(){
    loadScreen = new LoadScreen();
    contentPane.add(loadScreen.getLoadScreen(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.pack();
}

public void makePlayScreen(Player player){
    contentPane.remove(loadScreen.getLoadScreen());;
    playScreen = new PlayScreen(player);
    contentPane.add(playScreen.getPlayScreen());
    frame.pack();
}

public class LoadScreen{
    private JPanel loadScreen;
    public LoadScreen(){
        loadScreen = new JPanel();
        JButton play = new JButton("Play");
        JButton load = new JButton("Load");
        loadScreen.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1,0,0));
        loadScreen.add(play);
        loadScreen.add(load);
        play.addActionListener(new OpenActionListener());
        load.addActionListener(new LoadActionListener());
    }

    public class OpenActionListener implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            makePlayScreen(player);
        }
    }

}
```

}

The View class is first created. I manually call the makeLoadScreen() method (though I will change it later to do this automatically), which creates the LoadScreen described in the nested class. This gives a view of two buttons, play and load. Clicking play then creates the PlayScreen, where the problem is.

When it is run, the detailPanel is always shown in the top left, as intended. But the towerButtons panel disappears, and the "hello" button is shown, filling up the rest of the screen. If I switch lines 6 and 10, the "hello" button disappears and the towerButtons panel is shown, filling up the rest of the screen.

Instead I would like the towerButtons to show on the right, with the "hello" button in between this and the detailPanel.

Edits: added the rest of the code, should have done this earlier, sorry!
Edits2: The problem turns out to be with "towerButtons," nothing to do with the JPanel's overlaying.

Comment: For better help, post screenshots and a  [more complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which reproduces the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: Please cite the _similar posts_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like the towerButtons to show on the right, with the "hello" button in between this and the detailPanel.

The problem is probably somewhere else in your code, so I don't think this should help you, but here:

```
public class Example extends JFrame {

    Example() {

        JPanel playScreen = new JPanel();
        playScreen.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel towerButtons = new JPanel();
        towerButtons.add(new JLabel("towerButtons"));
        playScreen.add(towerButtons, BorderLayout.EAST);

        JPanel detailPanel = new JPanel();
        detailPanel.add(new JLabel("detailPanel"));
        playScreen.add(detailPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);

        playScreen.add(new JButton("hello"), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        add(playScreen);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        new Example();
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem was indeed somewhere else in the code, turns out the "towerButtons" JPanel wasn't been configured correctly, Therefore it produced a blank. Switching line 6 and 10 produced the opposite problem for an entirely different reason, so it was coincidence that the JPanel's seemed to overlay.